# Using uninititalized array C#

Tags: c#

I am using Visual Studio, .NET 8.0.

There is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Learn
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           int c;
           int[] arr;
           c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

           for (int i = 0; i <= c - 1; i++)
           {
               arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
           }
       }
   };
}
```

I tried to input this:

```
3
1
1
1
```

I get an error CS0165

How to fix that?

Comment: you can use List instead of array

Comment: Please write it to answers

Comment: or initalize your array before using it: `arr = new int[c]; `

Comment: It's also worth noting that using `int.Parse` on a user entered string isn't usually the best path. Users do not always type the right thing, and `int.Parse` will throw an exception if the string can't be parsed. If you use `int.TryParse` you can check if the entered data is correct and provide feedback to the user on error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get an error CS0165

The error *message* is more informative than just its error code:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'arr'

Indeed, that variable is unassigned/uninitialized:

```
int[] arr;
```

Think of it as a *placeholder* for an array, but currently there is no array there.  You can initialize that array once you know the length:

```
int c;
int[] arr;
c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
arr = new int[c];
```

Note also that declaration and initialization can happen on the same line:

```
int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = new int[c];
```

---

As others have suggested, a common approach in C# to collections of items is generic lists instead of plain arrays.  It's not a necessary change for the example shown, but something worth exploring as complexity grows.  A similar example using a generic list might be:

```
var list = new List<int>();
var length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    list.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```

Comment: Where by *a modern alternative to simple arrays is generic lists*, the word "modern" means "since 2005-10-27 when .NET 2 was released."

Comment: I wouldn't say an alternative like they replace arrays entirely. Even lists use arrays. An array was perfectly fine here, and the size was even known ahead of time